# Difference between fixed point and equilibrium point!

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

Let us consider a first order, autonomous and nonlinear DE:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$$

when will we get an equilibrium point and fixed point? Are they the same? I need some clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same thing, and there are several other synonyms too: rest point, critical point, steady state, etc.